# How to explain this contradiction with infimum and $\epsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, logic

If we have $\inf A$ of a set $A$, then $\inf A+ϵ$ is not a lower bound of $A$. There exists some elements $x$ of $A$ such that $x\in A$ and $x\in[\inf A,\inf A+\epsilon)$. However, $x<\inf A+\epsilon$ implies $x\leq\inf A$ which means these $x$ are lower bound of $A$. It contradicts the definition of infimum. How to explain it?

My Attempt: Suppose the only element in $[\inf A,\inf A+\epsilon)$ is the $\inf A$, then it is true that $\inf A \leq \inf A$ and $\inf A\in A$. However, it is not always true that $\inf A \in A$. If $\inf A\notin A$, then I have a contradiction that $x\in A$ and $x \leq \inf A$ at the same time.

Comment: "However, **x<infA+ϵ implies x≤infA** which means these x are lower bound of A. It contradicts the definition of infimum."   ** bracketed statement not true!

Comment: "However, x<infA+ϵ implies x≤infA"    No, it doesn't.  Let $x = \inf A + \frac {\epsilon}2$.  Then $x < \inf A + \epsilon$ but $ x > \inf A$.

Comment: $\epsilon$ is not a magic value.  It is a small number.  We use the symbol to mean that that what we say about it will be true for any number no matter how small and we want some observations that are true for all small numbers but the number *WE PICK* is just a small number.  It doesn't have any special properties of being smaller than anything else.    It's impossible to find a positive number $W$ (no matter what greek symbol you call it so that there aren't any $x$ between $A$ and $A + W$.  No matter what $W$ is, there is an $x$ between $A$ and $A+W$.

Comment: Psychologically and stylistically they should probably not have have said "$\inf A + \epsilon$ is not a lower bound"  they should have said "if $w > \inf A$ then $w$ is not a lower bound".  I doubt you would say "However $x < w$ and $w >\inf A$ implies $x \le \inf A$".  But if you set $w = \inf A + \epsilon$ or set $\epsilon = w - \inf A$ the statements are *EXACTLY* the same.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, I should say $w=infA+\epsilon$ instead of just saying $infA+\epsilon$. It makes sense for me now.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you learned the theorem "If $x<y+\epsilon$ for all positive $\epsilon$ then $x\leq y$" and have confused it with the falsehood "for all positive $\epsilon$, if $x<y+\epsilon$ then $x\leq y$."

Comment: I see why second statement is false but I am confusing now that when do we treat $\epsilon$ as fixed? And when do we treat $\epsilon$ as all possible positive number?

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be assuming something very special about $\epsilon$ when you write

> $x<inf A+\epsilon$ implies $x\le inf A$.

This would only be true if $\epsilon$ were "as small as possible" so that there would be no room between $inf A$ and $inf A + \epsilon$ for any more elements of $A$. But there is no such number: for any positive $\epsilon$, the number ${\epsilon\over 2}$ is also positive but $<\epsilon$.

For a concrete example, take $A$ to be the set of positive reals. Then $inf A=0$, and for every positive $\epsilon$ the number $\epsilon\over 2$ is an element of $A$ which is less than $inf A+\epsilon$.

---

As a far more minor aside, you're also implicitly assuming that $A$ does not have a least element - if $inf A\in A$ then for any positive $\epsilon$ the number $inf A$ is an element of $A$ less than $inf A+\epsilon$, so even if there were an $\epsilon$ with the above property - which, again,there isn't - we wouldn't have a contradiction in this case.

Comment: Yes, I assume there is no room between $infA$ and $infA + \epsilon$. So when we say $[infA, infA+\epsilon)$, we treat $\epsilon$ as fixed instead of "as small as possible"?

Comment: @jf1997 Yes - there is no smallest positive number, so it doesn't make sense to treat $\epsilon$ that way.

Comment: C'mon man, at least `\inf` properly!

Answer (score 1):

If $x < K+\epsilon$ for ***ALL*** $\epsilon > 0$ then $x \le K$.

But if $x < K + \epsilon$ for ***SOME*** $\epsilon > 0$ then $K < x  < K + \epsilon$ is very much possible.  (For example if $x = K + \frac \epsilon 2$)

It is true that for ***ALL*** $\epsilon > 0$ then $\inf A + \epsilon $ is not a lower bound and therefore that if $w$ is a lower bound of $A$ then $w \le \inf A$.  But for every $\epsilon > 0$ there will be some $x_\epsilon$ so that $\inf A \le x_\epsilon < \inf A + \epsilon$.  That is true for ***THAT*** $\epsilon > 0$.

However there are not any $x$ so that $\inf A < x < \inf A + \epsilon$ for ***ALL*** $\epsilon$.  But that is not what the statement is saying.  The statement is saying for ***THAT*** $\epsilon$ there is an $x$ so that $\inf A \le x < \inf A + \epsilon$.  Having $\inf A < x$ for ***THAT*** $\epsilon$ will not be a contradiction.

Comment: OK, I see that in this statement, we make $\epsilon$ be fixed, and there is no such a contradiction. But how can we distinguish "for all $\epsilon$" and "for some $\epsilon$" ?

Comment: so it is not true that there exist a $x∈A$ such that $infA<x<infA+ϵ$,$∀ϵ>0$. However, it is true that $∀ϵ>0$ there exists $x∈A$ such that $infA<x<infA+ϵ$?

Comment: Yes.   Just like there is no number $x>0$ so that $0 < x < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon  >0$, but for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $x$ (take $x = 0.9\epsilon$ for example) so that $0 < x < \epsilon$. .... This is *EXACTLY* like saying:  For every number $N$ there is a number that is bigger than $N$.  (Obvious.... if you say "a gazillion" I say "a gazillion and one) ... but there in no number $N$ that is bigger than all numbers. (Obvious..... if I say "a gazillion and one" you say that's not bigger than a gazillion and two")

Comment: Thanks, I find that I am comfortable with "for every".

Comment: "But how can we distinguish "for all ϵ" and "for some ϵ" "  They are completely different statements.  Some people like pie.  All people have lungs.  Not all people like pie.  No person doesn't have lungs.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between *all* $\epsilon$ and *some* $\epsilon$ needs to be made explicit or abundantly clear (if needed) in your language.

You can write:

> For every $\epsilon>0$ the number $\inf A+\epsilon$ is not a lower bound for $A$ and hence there exists a member $x_\epsilon\in A$ *corresponding to* $\epsilon$ such that $$\inf A\leq x_\epsilon <\inf A+\epsilon$$

The above statement is true and you don't get the conclusion $x_\epsilon\leq \inf A$ because the number $x_\epsilon$ is not fixed but rather depends on the value of $\epsilon$.

The logical part of definitions in elementary analysis is not difficult and best handled by writing in natural language rather than using logical symbols and technical jargon. Reserve these for those occasions when you want to intimidate your readers.

Also if you are unlucky to have read a theorem like (which is most likely the source of your confusion here)

> **(Unnecessary) Theorem**: If $x, y$ are real numbers such that $x<y+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$ then $x\leq y$.

then do translate it into

> **(Obvious) Fact**: There is no least positive real number.

Also treat the above obvious fact on par with *there is no least positive rational number* and *there is no greatest positive integer*.