# What's different two proposition? $x < y + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ vs $\forall \epsilon > 0$ , $x < y + \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis

What's different two proposition?

> $x, y \in\mathbb{R}$, $x < y + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ $\implies x \leq y$

versus

> $x, y \in\mathbb{R}$, $\forall \epsilon > 0$ , $x < y + \epsilon \implies x \leq y$

Is the second proposition false?

Could you prove that?

Comment: The second one is a little ambiguous without parentheses, unless there is an established order-of-operations I'm unaware of.   $(\forall \epsilon > 0$ , $x < y + \epsilon) \implies x \leq y$ is true but $\forall \epsilon > 0$ ($x < y + \epsilon \implies x \leq y)$ is false.

Comment: The first is a mix of English language and formal notation, a bad idea. in general. Pick on. I tend to avoid $\forall$ in English text, but will use some limited notation, like $=$ and $\in.$

Comment: In English, the first should be "If $x,y\in\mathbb R,$ and $x<y+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0,$ then $x\leq y.$" The second one is ambigous without the parentheses, as Jair commented.

Comment: Its the same as the difference between "I go to church every Sunday" and "every Sunday I go to church", that is, **no difference at all**. However, if you put "for all" at the end, then you must not replace the words "for all" with the symbol $\forall$. In fact, it's always bad form to replace the words with the symbol, but it's especially bad if "for all" is at the end. Also, rember that the expression "for all" is two words; "forall" is not a word in English.

Comment: I appreciate your comments,
Can that propositions are expressed like that "If <+ for all positive  then ≤" vs "for all positive , if <+ then ≤." by https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3475554/1038590 ?